# Why does my accordion move up when i click on it

Tags: html, css

[when the accordion are opened the div moves up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLVWc.png)

When the page loads, everything looks fine and perfectly placed, but when the accordions are clicked, the div containing the accordion and images moves up.

Here is my web https://gracious-euclid-6b6204.netlify.app/

EDIT :
I found out that the problem is with "Overflow : hidden" on the container that is causing the div to move up but if I do not use Overflow Hidden, my image will overflow what to do?

Thanks in advance for your kind help

```
.accordion {
  width: 57%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5.5rem;
}

.accordion h1 {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.accordion-item {
  /* display: flex; */
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid hsl(240, 5%, 91%);
}

.accordion-link {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: hsl(237, 12%, 33%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.accordion-link img {
  height: 100%;
}

.answer {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: hsl(240, 6%, 50%);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  /* display: none; */
  max-height: 0rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 200ms;
}

.accordion-link:hover {
  color: hsl(14, 88%, 65%);
}

.accordion-item:target .answer {
  max-height: 20rem;
}

.accordion-item:target .accordion-link {
  color: hsl(238, 29%, 16%);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.accordion-item:target .accordion-link img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Its hard to find the problem with a screenshot, can you please give URL to the website or create a codepen, so we can help you better.

Comment: can you try creating a jsfiddle or codepen so it will be easier for us

Answer (score 0):

Don't use #id in href....if you use it's change the url and because of that it's showing up every time...

use this...

```js
function myFunction (id){
  if($(".content"+id).is(":hidden")){
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content"+id).slideDown();
  }
}
```

```css
.accPanel {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}
.accPanel .heading {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.accPanel .content {
  display: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.accPanel:first-child .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accPanel">
    <div class="heading" onclick="myFunction(1)">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="content content1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque egestas rhoncus bibendum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam faucibus nisi sit amet sagittis accumsan. Pellentesque porttitor sodales tortor a scelerisque.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accPanel">
    <div class="heading" onclick="myFunction(2)">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="content content2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque egestas rhoncus bibendum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam faucibus nisi sit amet sagittis accumsan. Pellentesque porttitor sodales tortor a scelerisque.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accPanel">
    <div class="heading" onclick="myFunction(3)">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="content content3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque egestas rhoncus bibendum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam faucibus nisi sit amet sagittis accumsan. Pellentesque porttitor sodales tortor a scelerisque.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accPanel">
    <div class="heading" onclick="myFunction(4)">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="content content4">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque egestas rhoncus bibendum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam faucibus nisi sit amet sagittis accumsan. Pellentesque porttitor sodales tortor a scelerisque.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```